# On PayU WordPress plugin after payment complete the order status still shows Pending payment

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment

I am trying to add payU payment gateway to my WooCommerce website but the official plugin is not working so I tried to make my own but after the payment completing the order its status still shows as "pending payment".

However, I am receiving payment on my PayU Account.

````
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'woocommerce_payupaisa_init', 0);
define('payupaisa_imgdir', WP_PLUGIN_URL . "/" . plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/images/');

function woocommerce_payupaisa_init(){
    if(!class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')) return;

    if( isset($_GET['msg']) && !empty($_GET['msg']) ){
        add_action('the_content', 'payupaisa_showMessage');
    }
    function payupaisa_showMessage($content){
            return '<div class="'.htmlentities($_GET['type']).'">'.htmlentities(urldecode($_GET['msg'])).'</div>'.$content;
    }

    /**
     * Gateway class
     */
    class WC_payupaisa extends WC_Payment_Gateway{
        public function __construct(){
            $this->id                   = 'payupaisa';
            $this->method_title         = 'PayU Paisa';
            $this->method_description   = "Redefining Payments, Simplifying Lives";
            $this->has_fields           = false;
            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();
            if ( $this->settings['showlogo'] == "yes" ) {
                $this->icon             = payupaisa_imgdir . 'logo.png';
            }           
            $this->title            = $this->settings['title'];
            $this->redirect_page_id = $this->settings['redirect_page_id'];
            $this -> enable_currency_conversion      = $this -> settings['enable_currency_conversion'];
            if ( $this->settings['testmode'] == "yes" ) {
                $this->liveurl          = 'https://test.payu.in/_payment';
                $this->merchant_id      = "gtKFFx";
                $this->salt             = "eCwWELxi";
                $this->description      = $this->settings['description'].
                                        "<br/><br/><u>Test Mode is <strong>ACTIVE</strong>, use following Credit Card details:-</u><br/>".
                                        "Test Card Name: <strong><em style='#999999;'>any name</em></strong><br/>".
                                        "Test Card Number: <strong>5123456789012346</strong><br/>".
                                        "Test Card CVV: <strong>123</strong><br/>".
                                        "Test Card Expiry: <strong>01/2020</strong><br/>";
            } else {
                $this->liveurl          = 'https://secure.payu.in/_payment';
                $this->merchant_id      = $this->settings['merchant_id'];
                $this->salt             = $this->settings['salt'];
                $this->description      = $this->settings['description'];
            }                   
            $this->msg['message']   = "";
            $this->msg['class']     = "";
                    
            add_action('init', array(&$this, 'check_payupaisa_response'));
            //update for woocommerce >2.0
            add_action( 'woocommerce_api_' . strtolower( get_class( $this ) ), array( $this, 'check_payupaisa_response' ) );
            
            if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.0.0', '>=' ) ) {
                /* 2.0.0 */
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( &$this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            } else {
                /* 1.6.6 */
                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways', array( &$this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            }
            
            add_action('woocommerce_receipt_payupaisa', array(&$this, 'receipt_page'));
        }
    
        function init_form_fields(){
            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title'         => __('Enable/Disable', 'nilesh'),
                    'type'          => 'checkbox',
                    'label'         => __('Enable PayU Paisa Payment Module.', 'nilesh'),
                    'default'       => 'no',
                    'description'   => 'Show in the Payment List as a payment option'
                ),
                'title' => array(
                    'title'         => __('Title:', 'nilesh'),
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'default'       => __('Online Payment', 'nilesh'),
                    'description'   => __('This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'nilesh'),
                    'desc_tip'      => true
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'title'         => __('Description:', 'nilesh'),
                    'type'          => 'textarea',
                    'default'       => __('Pay securely by Credit or Debit Card or Internet Banking through PayU Secure Servers.', 'nilesh'),
                    'description'   => __('This controls the description which the user sees during checkout.', 'nilesh'),
                    'desc_tip'      => true
                ),
                'merchant_id' => array(
                    'title'         => __('Merchant KEY', 'nilesh'),
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'description'   => __('Given to Merchant by PayU Money'),
                    'desc_tip'      => true
                ),
                'salt' => array(
                    'title'         => __('Merchant SALT', 'nilesh'),
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'description'   =>  __('Given to Merchant by PayU Money', 'nilesh'),
                    'desc_tip'      => true
                ),
                'showlogo' => array(
                    'title'         => __('Show Logo', 'nilesh'),
                    'type'          => 'checkbox',
                    'label'         => __('Show the "PayU Paisa" logo in the Payment Method section for the user', 'nilesh'),
                    'default'       => 'yes',
                    'description'   => __('Tick to show "PayU Paisa" logo'),
                    'desc_tip'      => true
                ),
                'enable_currency_conversion' => array(
                    'title' => __('Currency Conversion to INR?', 'nilesh'),
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'label' => __('Enable Currency Conversion to INR.', 'nilesh'),
                    'default' => 'no',
                    'description'=> __('converted to equivalent amount in INR for faster payment processing'),
                    'desc_tip'      => true
                ),
                'testmode' => array(
                    'title'         => __('TEST Mode', 'nilesh'),
                    'type'          => 'checkbox',
                    'label'         => __('Enable PayU Paisa TEST Transactions.', 'nilesh'),
                    'default'       => 'no',
                    'description'   => __('Tick to run TEST Transaction on the PayU Paisa platform'),
                    'desc_tip'      => true
                ),
                'redirect_page_id' => array(
                    'title'         => __('Return Page'),
                    'type'          => 'select',
                    'options'       => $this->payupaisa_get_pages('Select Page'),
                    'description'   => __('URL of success page', 'nilesh'),
                    'desc_tip'      => true
                )
            );
        }
        /**
         * Admin Panel Options
         * - Options for bits like 'title' and availability on a country-by-country basis
         **/
        public function admin_options(){
            echo '<h3>'.__('PayU Paisa', 'nilesh').'</h3>';
            echo '<p>'.__('Redefining Payments, Simplifying Lives! Empowering any business to collect money online within minutes').'</p>';
            echo '<table class="form-table">';
            // Generate the HTML For the settings form.
            $this->generate_settings_html();
            echo '</table>';
        }
        /**
         *  There are no payment fields for techpro, but we want to show the description if set.
         **/
        function payment_fields(){
            if($this->description) echo wpautop(wptexturize($this->description));
        }
        /**
        * Receipt Page
        **/
        function receipt_page($order){
            echo '<p>'.__('Thank you for your order, please click the button below to pay with PayU.', 'nilesh').'</p>';
            echo $this->generate_payupaisa_form($order);
        }
        /*currency convertor API*/
        function currency_convert($currency_from,$currency_to,$currency_input)
        {
            if ($currency_from != $currency_to)
            {
                $yql_base_url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
                $yql_query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("'.$currency_from.$currency_to.'")';
                $yql_query_url = $yql_base_url . "?q=" . urlencode($yql_query);
                $yql_query_url .= "&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
                $yql_session = curl_init($yql_query_url);
                curl_setopt($yql_session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
                $yqlexec = curl_exec($yql_session);
                $yql_json =  json_decode($yqlexec,true);
                $currency_output = (float) $currency_input*$yql_json['query']['results']['rate']['Rate'];
                return $currency_output;
            }
            else
            {
                return $currency_input;
            }
        }       
        /**
        * Generate payu button link
        **/
        function generate_payupaisa_form($order_id){
            global $woocommerce;
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
            $myTxnId = substr(str_shuffle(md5('abcdefghijklmnop9876543210')),0,8);
            
            if ( $this->redirect_page_id == "" || $this->redirect_page_id == 0 ) {
                $redirect_url = $order->get_checkout_order_received_url();
            } else {
                $redirect_url = get_permalink($this->redirect_page_id);
            }

            //For wooCoomerce 2.0
            if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.0.0', '>=' ) ) {
                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( 'wc-api', get_class( $this ), $redirect_url );
            }

            $productinfo = "Order $order_id";
            /*check if currency converstion is enable*/
            $the_order_total = $order->order_total;
            if($this->enable_currency_conversion=='yes')
            {
                $the_order_total = $this->currency_convert($the_currency, 'INR', $the_order_total);
                $the_display_msg = "<small> $the_currency has been converted to equivalent amount in INR for faster payment processing.</small><br />";
            }
            /*-------------------------*/
            $str = $this->merchant_id."|".$myTxnId."|".$the_order_total."|".$productinfo."|".$order->billing_first_name."|".$order->billing_email."|||||||||||".$this->salt;

            $hash = hash('sha512', $str);

            $payupaisa_args = array(
                'key'           => $this->merchant_id,
                'hash'          => $hash,
                'txnid'         => $myTxnId,
                'amount'        => $the_order_total,
                'debug'         =>  1,
                'firstname'     => $order->billing_first_name,
                'email'         => $order->billing_email,
                'phone'         => $order->billing_phone,
                'productinfo'   => $productinfo,
                'surl'          => $redirect_url,
                'furl'          => $redirect_url,
                'lastname'      => $order->billing_last_name,
                'address1'      => $order->billing_address_1,
                'address2'      => $order->billing_address_2,
                'city'          => $order->billing_city,
                'state'         => $order->billing_state,
                'country'       => $order->billing_country,
                'zipcode'       => $order->billing_postcode,
                'curl'          => $redirect_url,
                'pg'            => 'NB'
            );
            $payupaisa_args_array = array();
            foreach($payupaisa_args as $key => $value){
                $payupaisa_args_array[] = "<input type='hidden' name='$key' value='$value'/>";
            }
            
            return '    <form action="'.$this->liveurl.'" method="post" id="payupaisa_payment_form">
                ' . implode('', $payupaisa_args_array) . '
                <input type="submit" class="button-alt" id="submit_payupaisa_payment_form" value="'.__('Pay via PayU Paisa', 'nilesh').'" /> <a class="button cancel" href="'.$order->get_cancel_order_url().'">'.__('Cancel order &amp; restore cart', 'nilesh').'</a>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function(){
                    jQuery("body").block({
                        message: "'.__('Thank you for your order. We are now redirecting you to Payment Gateway to make payment.', 'nilesh').'",
                        overlayCSS: {
                            background      : "#fff",
                            opacity         : 0.6
                        },
                        css: {
                            padding         : 20,
                            textAlign       : "center",
                            color           : "#555",
                            border          : "3px solid #aaa",
                            backgroundColor : "#fff",
                            cursor          : "wait",
                            lineHeight      : "32px"
                        }
                    });
                    jQuery("#submit_payupaisa_payment_form").click();});
                    </script>
                </form>';
        }
        /**
        * Process the payment and return the result
        **/
        function process_payment($order_id){
            global $woocommerce;
            $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
            
            if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.1.0', '>=' ) ) {
                /* 2.1.0 */
                $checkout_payment_url = $order->get_checkout_payment_url( true );
            } else {
                /* 2.0.0 */
                $checkout_payment_url = get_permalink( get_option ( 'woocommerce_pay_page_id' ) );
            }

            return array(
                'result' => 'success', 
                'redirect' => add_query_arg(
                    'order', 
                    $order->id, 
                    add_query_arg(
                        'key', 
                        $order->order_key, 
                        $checkout_payment_url                       
                    )
                )
            );
        }
        /**
        * Check for valid payu server callback
     **/
           
        function check_payupaisa_response(){
            global $woocommerce;
            if( isset($_REQUEST['txnid']) && isset($_REQUEST['mihpayid']) ){
                $order_id = $_REQUEST['udf1'];
                if($order_id != ''){
                    try{
                        $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
                        $hash = $_REQUEST['hash'];
                        $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
                        $checkhash = hash('sha512', "$this->salt|||||||||||$_REQUEST[email]|$_REQUEST[firstname]|$_REQUEST[productinfo]|$_REQUEST[amount]|$_REQUEST[txnid]|$this->merchant_id");
                        $transauthorised = false;
                        

                        
                        if( $order->status !=='completed' ){
                            if($hash == $checkhash){
                                $status = strtolower($status);
                                if($status=="success"){
                                    $transauthorised = true;
                                    $this->msg['message'] = "Thank you for shopping with us. Your account has been charged and your transaction is successful.";
                                    $this->msg['class'] = 'woocommerce-message';
                                    if($order->status == 'processing'){
                                        $order->add_order_note('PayU Paisa ID: '.$_REQUEST['mihpayid'].' ('.$_REQUEST['txnid'].')<br/>PG: '.$_REQUEST['PG_TYPE'].'<br/>Bank Ref: '.$_REQUEST['bank_ref_num']);
                                    }else{
                                        $order->payment_complete();
                                        $order->add_order_note('PayU Paisa payment successful.<br/>PayU Paisa ID: '.$_REQUEST['mihpayid'].' ('.$_REQUEST['txnid'].')<br/>PG: '.$_REQUEST['PG_TYPE'].'<br/>Bank Ref: '.$_REQUEST['bank_ref_num']);
                                        $woocommerce -> cart -> empty_cart();
                                    }
                                    

                                    
                                }else if($status=="pending"){
                                    $this->msg['message'] = "Thank you for shopping with us. Right now your payment status is pending. We will keep you posted regarding the status of your order through eMail";
                                    $this->msg['class'] = 'woocommerce-info';
                                    $order->add_order_note('PayU Paisa payment status is pending<br/>PayU Paisa ID: '.$_REQUEST['mihpayid'].' ('.$_REQUEST['txnid'].')<br/>PG: '.$_REQUEST['PG_TYPE'].'<br/>Bank Ref: '.$_REQUEST['bank_ref_num']);
                                    $order->update_status('on-hold');
                                    $woocommerce -> cart -> empty_cart();
                                }else{
                                    $this->msg['class'] = 'woocommerce-error';
                                    $this->msg['message'] = "Thank you for shopping with us. However, the transaction has been declined.";
                                    $order->add_order_note('Transaction ERROR: '.$_REQUEST['error'].'<br/>PayU Paisa ID: '.$_REQUEST['mihpayid'].' ('.$_REQUEST['txnid'].')');
                                }
                            }else{
                                $this->msg['class'] = 'error';
                                $this->msg['message'] = "Security Error. Illegal access detected.";
                            }
                            if($transauthorised==false){
                                $order->update_status('failed');
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception $e){
                        $msg = "Error";
                    }
                }

                $redirect_url = ($this->redirect_page_id=="" || $this->redirect_page_id==0)?get_site_url() . "/":get_permalink($this->redirect_page_id);
                //For wooCoomerce 2.0
                $redirect_url = add_query_arg( array('msg'=> urlencode($this->msg['message']), 'type'=>$this->msg['class']), $redirect_url );

                wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
                exit;
            }
        }
        // get all pages
        function payupaisa_get_pages($title = false, $indent = true) {
            $wp_pages = get_pages('sort_column=menu_order');
            $page_list = array();
            if ($title) $page_list[] = $title;
            foreach ($wp_pages as $page) {
                $prefix = '';
                // show indented child pages?
                if ($indent) {
                    $has_parent = $page->post_parent;
                    while($has_parent) {
                        $prefix .=  ' - ';
                        $next_page = get_post($has_parent);
                        $has_parent = $next_page->post_parent;
                    }
                }
                // add to page list array array
                $page_list[$page->ID] = $prefix . $page->post_title;
            }
            return $page_list;
            }
        

    }
    
    
        /**
        * Add the Gateway to WooCommerce
        **/
        function woocommerce_add_payupaisa_gateway($methods) {
            $methods[] = 'WC_payupaisa';
            return $methods;
        }
        add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'woocommerce_add_payupaisa_gateway' );
    }
    ```
````

Comment: I had a same problem. Fixed it by creating my own plugin modifications. Did not find any solution for it with the support.

Answer (score -1):

I well understand that after receiving the payment, the status of the order does not change?
Do you have auto-receive enabled in the plugin and in the PayU panel?

[image]

Your server filtering IP addresses or are you using a tool like CloudFlare?
If you filter IP addresses, remember to allow IPs used by PayU to send the notifications. These are:

**Production**

```
185.68.12.10, 185.68.12.11, 185.68.12.12, 185.68.12.26, 185.68.12.27, 185.68.12.28
```

**SANDBOX**

```
185.68.14.10, 185.68.14.11, 185.68.14.12, 185.68.14.26, 185.68.14.27, 185.68.14.28
```

Comment: Dear Dominik,   can you suggest me with the code I have to put on my plugin as I don't have any auto-receive option for notifying my website that it received the payment and the item details btw it on woocommerce.

Comment: Are you from india? I see '.in' in PayU domain. Have you read this documentation? https://www.payumoney.com/dev-guide/apireference.html. I also recommend https://developers.payu.com/en/restapi.html - here is everything  well described. Let me know what you think.

Comment: It fixed by using other plugins.